# "Could Not Find A Part Of The Path"

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, iis

Need help with a web application I am writing in ASP.NET the code runs fine on LocalHost but bombs with a ‘Could not find part of path’ error when I try to run it on the server (IIS 7.5 on Windows Server 2008 R2).
What is bombing is a section where I am testing to see if a directory exists (If Directory.Exists) on our network transfer drive named after the users logon name so I am guessing my problem is permission or security related (see below).

I am already using impersonation in the sites web.config file (see below) for other applications and I authenticate the user to our active directory based on their username (environment.username) and their form entered network password.

I have tried using UNCs (the error becomes access to path is denied) also a security manager class I came across and two methods to directly map the drives I need all to no avail.

What I need to be able to do is to copy a prototype file from one network location to this user transfer folder under another name as well as write a CSV file to the same location.

Did surf around and look at the other related questions / answers and some seemed close but none had the copy to network component... (Closest: System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path)

Web.config

```
<authentication mode="Windows"/>
<authorization> <deny users="?"/> </authorization>
<identity impersonate="true"/>
```

CODE -

```
    Public Sub MakeItemLoaderFile(ByVal Numrec As Integer)
        "   Truncating Datastring and writealltext for readability
        Dim DateStr As String = Now.Month & "/" & Now.Day & "/" & Now.Year
        Dim seednumber As Integer = (HighNumber - Numrec) + 1
        Dim datastring As String = ""
        Dim TemplateFile As String = "J:\Shared\Cad\TEMPLATES\CORP-D.DWG"
        Try
            If Directory.Exists("T:\" & username) = False Then 
                FileSystem.MkDir("T:\" & username)
            End if
            Dim ItemLoaderFile As String = "T:\" & username & _
                    "\LoaderFile-" & seednumber.ToString & "-" & Now.Day & _
                    Now.Month & Now.Year & ".CSV"
            If Not FileIO.FileSystem.FileExists(ItemLoaderFile) Then
                   My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText(ItemLoaderFile, _                        
                       "Item,Title,Comment,Facility Name,..." & vbCrLf, _ 
                        True, System.Text.Encoding.ASCII)
                   For stepcount As Integer = 0 To Numrec - 1
                       FileSystem.FileCopy(TemplateFile, "T:\" & username 
                           & "\" & seednumber.ToString & ".DWG")
                       datastring = "T:\" & username & "\" &                 
                           seednumber.ToString)
                       FileSystem.WriteAllText(ItemLoaderFile, datastring _
                           & vbCrLf, True)
                       seednumber = seednumber + 1
                   Next
             End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            popmessage("Drawing Numbers - MakeItemLoaderFile Error: " & _ 
            ex.Message.ToString, "CADWEB Drawing Numbers Error")
        End Try
    End Sub
```

Comment: The website is running in an AppPool.  The AppPool is running under a user account, and if you have not changed the AppPool's user account to one that can access files on T: then I would expect an error.

Comment: Also, you'll have to use the UNC path instead of T:, because the AppPool user account is not going to have a T: drive mapped.

Comment: Thank you Tony I will look into this and post back my results.